# How can i take element form beautifulsoup skipping first few and last few elements?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is the snippet

```
containers = file.findAll("tr")
len(containers)      # return 18

type(containers)     # returns bs4.element.ResultSet
```

How can I get element inside "tr" for only 3rd to 17th item i.e by excluding 1,2 and last items form the ResultSet?

Comment: then use index slice `[3:18]`

Comment: Thank you. That was quick and very accurate response. I was just iterating using for/ifs. This one is a lot better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the result of findAll method in BeautifulSoup is a list you can slice the list to get the relevant elements from it in you case

```
containers = file.findAll("tr")
containers[3:18]
```

or

```
containers = [v for i, v in enumerate(containers) if 2 < i < 18]
```

if you would like to do it by list comparison